# ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token: keyword (else)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

I have a problem in app rails.
My app works fine on the development server, but on my host it does not work when uploading, and throws me this error on any path of my application.

I checked all the drivers to see if there are any closures, but I did not find anything unusual.

Here I show my log production.

```
I, [2017-07-06T02:47:57.031902 #30638]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 187.204.162.35 at 2017-07-06 02:47:57 +0200
I, [2017-07-06T02:47:57.046063 #30638]  INFO -- : Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
I, [2017-07-06T02:47:57.608254 #30638]  INFO -- :   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (535.1ms)
I, [2017-07-06T02:47:57.608542 #30638]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 562ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2017-07-06T02:47:57.610259 #30638] FATAL -- :
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: Unexpected token: keyword (else)):
    130:             <div class="row">
    131:
    132:             <div class="col-md-4">
    133:               <%= image_tag("mision.png", :style => "width: 50px; margin: auto; display: block;", class:  "img-responsive") %>
    134:               <h3 class="text-center" style="color: #004467;"><strong>MISIÓN</strong></h3>
    135:               <p style=" text-align: justify;">Hacer realidad los sueños de nuestros clientes Lo logramos con: propuestas y soluciones claras, asesoría persona$
    136:               </div>
  app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:133:in `_app_views_welcome_index_html_erb___3018899638396619987_70193610437540'
```

Comment: What's on your `index.html.erb`?

Comment: https://github.com/HugoGtz/Fidei/blob/production/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb